# ServiceController in C# not taking arguments

Tags: c#

Good evening, I am fairly new in C# programming you can not even call me a noob.

I try to find my way and sadly I have no way for education other than the internet and stack overflow (thanks for stack overflow.)

The problem:
I want to start and stop a service in C# working with Net 4.0 here.

I have added a reference to System.ServiceProcess and I am set the following in the top of the program

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Now I have the following function for me:

```
 // Below is the service start and stop code

        public void ServiceStart(string SVName)
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(SVName);
            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
        }
        public void ServiceStop(string SVName)
        {
            ServiceController service = new ServiceController(SVName);
            service.Stop();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
        }

// End of Service Restart Code
```

The problem I have is that the function gives me 4 errors 2 errors repeat for the "Stop" function.

> 'FM_MW.ServiceController' does not contain a definition for 'Start' and no accessible extension method >'Start' accepting a first argument of type 'FM_MW.ServiceController' could be found (are you missing a >using directive or an assembly reference?)

and

> FM_MW.ServiceController' does not contain a definition for 'WaitForStatus' and no accessible extension >method 'WaitForStatus' accepting a first argument of type 'FM_MW.ServiceController' could be found (are >you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

These 2 errors repeat for the stop function as well. Please help me I really have no idea anymore I am sitting in front of this problem for 4 hours now I know basically nothing and all I do is try to learn through the documentation and stack overflow.

Addition:
Oh I am sorry I should have explained more about my program

The program Needs to stop a service then he updates files, then he checks the files updates the database and then he should restart the stopped services.

I need these functions to stop a service so that I can update files.

Comment: Note the namespace name in the error message.  Just don't create your own class named ServiceController.  Or use the full type name to resolve the ambiguity, `new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(SVName)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Problem myself after long long search.

It seems I created a function somewhere in the code with the auto fix.

The serviceController tried to access that code. and not the system.

Means I had

Form_ServiceController   [as my own function]

and not

System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController

That was the problem after I deleted my rogue code snippet everything worked as intended.

!!